# SKScene, detect when 2 SKSpriteNodes become within x range of each other?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skscene

I'm new to SpriteKit, and I'm not sure if what I'm trying to accomplish is not already possible with built-in objects such as SKPhysics and SKRegion.

In short, I need an event handler to trigger a custom subclass of an SKSpriteNode once an enemy SKSpriteNode enters within a certain range.

I'm building an RTS and so far the biggest problem I've been facing for a few days now is how to have 2 SKSpriteNodes detect whether or not they are in close range of each other.

Right now, my solution is rather hacky it seems. Before an SKSpriteNode in my SKScene moves `50` or `-50` points by `X` or `Y` anywhere in the scene, it will first check if that movement is permitted.

Here's an example for my abstract class "PathFindingUnit":

```
override func OrderUnitToMoveOneStepLEFT() -> Bool {
    if isDead == true { return false }
    sprite.playFaceLeftAnimation()
    angleFacing = UnitFaceAngle.Left

    updateMovementBlockerPosition()
    let destination = round(sprite.position.x) - UnitDefaultProperty.Movement.Range
    var pointDestination = sprite.position
    pointDestination.x = destination


    if thereIsAnObstacleInTheWay(pointDestination) == false {
        activateEnemiesNearby(pointDestination)
        sprite.playWalkLEFTAnimation()

            self.sprite.runAction(SKAction.moveToX(self.roundToFifties(destination), duration: 0.2))


        angleFacing = UnitFaceAngle.Left
        unitDidMove(pointDestination)

        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

If this method returns true, the unit's sprite will perform an SKAction to move -50 on the X dimension. Otherwise, nothing will happen.

This is how the unit sprite determines whether or not it's okay to move:

```
func thereIsAnObstacleInTheWay(destination: CGPoint) -> Bool {
    let getNodesAtDestination = ReferenceOfGameScene!.nodesAtPoint(destination)
    for node in getNodesAtDestination {
        if node is SKBlockMovementSpriteNode {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

For the most part, it's about as powerful as the pathfinding is for units in Warcraft II. But whenever I try to improve upon this method, I'm constantly running into:

`Exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xf91002028))`

I started getting this issue a lot as soon as I implemented: `activateEnemiesNearby(pointDestination)`

Since the unit `self`, will activate other units and order them to attack `self`.

So in conclusion, should Units with an `SKSpriteNode` in an `SKScene` be calling methods of other Units with a similar `SKSpriteNode` by invoking the enemy unit's MOVE_TO_POINT method within itself by using reference variables about the enemy unit within itself?

I tried using SKPhysics which worked somewhat well, but the SKSpriteNodes position jitters due to the collision physics effects that happen when 2 SKSpriteNodes touch.

I thought about using SKRegion, but I had a lot of trouble figuring out how they are invoked and inserted into the SKScene, and the official apple docs on SKRegion seems very limited:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKRegion_Ref/

Are SKRegions best for "Unit sight"? in order for Units to detect that an enemy is approaching?

Comment: SKRegion is not what you want,  that won't send any events,  it is used to define if a point lies in a region,  so you would be using this to determine sprite to ground,  if you want to see if 2 sprites are within range,  then SKPhysicsBody could help, but may be expensive. if not done correctly

Comment: by default collision mask is set to 0xFFFFFFFF on all bodies,set it to 0

Answer (score 0):

I'm incline to use `SKPhysicsBody` to detect if a body collide with a specific zone marked with another `SKPhysicBody`, for example a zone created with a specific `CGPath` so you can do:

```
SKPhysicsBody.init(edgeLoopFromPath: zonePath!) // zonePath is a CGPath
```

however if you don't want to use it there is also this little function that could help you with your calculations:

```
func getDistance(p1:CGPoint,p2:CGPoint)->CGFloat {
    let xDist = (p2.x - p1.x)
    let yDist = (p2.y - p1.y)
    return CGFloat(sqrt((xDist * xDist) + (yDist * yDist)))
}
```

About this last way, you could find useful also these methods:

```
/* Return true if `point' is contained in `rect', false otherwise. */

@available(iOS 2.0, *)
public func CGRectContainsPoint(rect: CGRect, _ point: CGPoint) -> Bool

/* Return true if `rect2' is contained in `rect1', false otherwise. `rect2'
   is contained in `rect1' if the union of `rect1' and `rect2' is equal to
   `rect1'. */

@available(iOS 2.0, *)
public func CGRectContainsRect(rect1: CGRect, _ rect2: CGRect) -> Bool

/* Return true if `rect1' intersects `rect2', false otherwise. `rect1'
   intersects `rect2' if the intersection of `rect1' and `rect2' is not the
   null rect. */

@available(iOS 2.0, *)
public func CGRectIntersectsRect(rect1: CGRect, _ rect2: CGRect) -> Bool
```

Comment: This is an RTS,  I would be avoiding SQRT as much as possible,  Distance squared works fine,  he just needs to make sure the enemy is closer than distance squared